# Error while installing aws autoscaling command line tools on linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am installing AWS Autoscaling tools on linux redhat, But unfortunately the `as-cmd` command is not working.

I am getting this error :

```
-bash: as-cmd: command not found
```

How to resolve the error ?

Any lead is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Answer your question:**

run below:

```
$ updatedb
$ locate as-cmd
```

This should provide you the path of the command like `/usr/bin/as-cmd`. Either you should use this complete path while running the command OR you need to update your `$PATH` variable to include this path. Google if you want to know how to update `PATH` variable.

**Now, some suggestions:**

You should not use `as-cmd` anymore. Please use [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html). Here is the [AWS CLI relevant autoscaling commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/index.html)

The reason being, as-cmd is not maintained by Amazon anymore and all the old CLI features have been exported to `AWS CLI`. `AWS CLI` is a one stop shop for all the AWS Services unlike older CLIs where you had to install a separate CLI for individual services.

AWS CLI provides output in JSON format which is much more easier to parse.

BESIDES, You don't have to play with CLI for autoscaling. Now, you can do the same job via [AWS Console](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/12/10/auto-scaling-console/).

Comment: But I tried to use the AUtoscaling feature on Console but the things were not working fine.

Comment: echo $PATH is giving the output : /bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/

Comment: I have set the PATH of Autoscaling folder but its not showing here

Comment: locate as-cmd is giving : 
/usr/local/AutoScaling-1.0.61.4/bin/as-cmd
/usr/local/AutoScaling-1.0.61.4/bin/as-cmd.cmd

Comment: `/usr/local/AutoScaling-1.0.61.4/bin/as-cmd` this is what you are looking for. You need to add `/usr/local/AutoScaling-1.0.61.4/bin` to you `PATH` variable.

Comment: the path variabale contains : `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/:$AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME/bin:$EC2_HOME/bin `

Comment: /usr/local/AutoScaling-1.0.61.4

Comment: but path variable shows `/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/:/bin:/bin
`

Comment: It is not showing autoscaling path in it. how ever i have started a new session

Comment: which file have you written `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/:$AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME/bin‌​:$EC2_HOME/bin` ? you need to source it. e.g. if above line is writtner in `~/.bashrc` then run `source ~/.bashrc`.